# Wait for Autoscaling to start

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, autoscaling

Is there a way to wait for autoscaling to start its activity once we modify the desired capacity in Autoscaling Group ? I am looking for something in AWS SDK Java.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "a way to wait for autoscaling to start its activity"? Are you looking for a way to programmatically detect whether instances have been launched under Auto Scaling? Did you try using [`DescribeAutoScalingGroups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/autoscaling/AmazonAutoScalingClient.html#describeAutoScalingGroups--)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#get indexer cluster members
ids=""
while [ "$ids" = "" ]; do
  ids=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $INDEXER_ASG --region $REGION --query AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[].InstanceId --output text)
  sleep 1
done
for ID in $ids;
do
    IP=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $ID --region $REGION --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress --output text)
done
```